# What are the physics behind the torque trick that uses a single match to hold a water bottle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, torque

https://youtu.be/CO5YUrbFTig?si=6HBL6tsSZqS6EWkq

I have seen a lot of videos about the same physics trick lately.
How would I be able to do this trick myself and find out what forces are interacting in this situation, also calculating the exact magnitude of force.

Answer (score 1):

See the free body diagram of the system of matches, string and bottle below. It shows the two external forces acting on the system, the normal force of the table and the force of gravity on the bottle. The mass of the matchsticks and string are ignored.

Though they don't show the complete profile of the bottle hanging down and the matchsticks on the table, you can see that the bottle hangs in such a way that its center of gravity is behind the edge of the table.  That creates a clockwise moment about the edge of the table (point O in the free body diagram below. Note the string wrapped around the bottle cap keeps the bottle oriented as shown).

The normal force of the table equals to the weight of the bottle and is in line with the COG of the bottle providing a counter-clockwise moment equal to the clockwise moment of the normal force. Thus the sum of the vertical forces and sum of the moments about O are zero and the system is in equilibrium.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I saw another explanation(https://youtu.be/Gtj86XkTmhQ?si=_GzG-tURqjxCyE2H) where it says that the COG of the bottle is aligned with O which makes the torque 0, and the force of the diagonal match in the diagram creates an upward force to the match on top of the table which compensates the normal force. I believe your explanation is probably right but if then, can u explain why just because the COG is moved backwards it compensates the normal force, when it is connected to the rope which is connected to the match at point O. Sorry for my lack of knowledge :(

Comment: @이윤지 what you are describing is correct but the role of the diagonal matchstick is to transmit force’s INTERNAL to the matchstick/bottle/string system. To determine equilibrium of the SYSTEM it is only necessary to consider the sum of the forces and moments due to the forces acting EXTERNALLY on the system (the table and gravity), which is the approach I took